# Split a dataframe by unique values in a dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, mean

I'm looking to analyze the ABV and Style of beer, and then take an average for graphing. I have all the beer styles and their ABV in a dataframe, I'm looking to create seperate Dataframes for each style, and then take the average of that styles ABV.
I've tried groupby and got nothing.

What I want to accomplish:

-Split dataframe into multiple dataframe by style which would include all ABV's per that style (there are some duplicate ABV values and 90 Styles, 71 unique ABV's)

-Take the average of each style

-Graph in a scatter plot.

Data Frame:

[image: Data frame]]

Comment: Pleas post your dataframe as text (it's hard to extract data from images!)

Comment: Also, I'm not sure a scattter plot makes sense here: you'll only have one datapoint (the mean ABV) for each style (which is categorical, not numeric). What are you trying to represent in your plot?

Comment: Still working on figuring out how to put the dataframe as text. But yeah, I'm thinking bar now.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find documentation on iterating through groups and ran passed this loop into it. This sorted it by style

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np



beers_csv = pd.read_csv("Resources/cleaned_beer.csv")
dropped_beers_csv = beers_csv.drop(columns=["Unnamed: 0", "Brewery ID", "Brewery", "City", "IBU", "State", "OZ.", "Beer"])

beer_data =  dropped_beers_csv
grouped = beer_data.groupby('Style')

for name, group in grouped:
    print(name)
    print(group)

grouped_beer = grouped.mean()

grouped_beer
```

It returned all the styles and the ABV (for example, it returned 2 Abby Single Ales and their ABV.

The last two lines just applied the mean function and spit out a dataframe with 90 rows, and running a unique count on my original csv file shows 90 unique styles, and then the mean function took the average of each group. Now I have a 90 row data frame containing each unique style and the average ABV for that style.